# Mostrar input segun privilegios

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario de usuario y contraseña que envia los datos al siguiente checklogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "database1";
$pass_db = "mypass";
$db_name = "usuariodatabase";
$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db,$pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) 
    {
    die("Conexion fallida con la base de datos" . $conexion->connect_error);
    }
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuario`='$username';";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){     
    }
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (password_verify($password, $row['contrasena'])) 
    { 
    //AQUI GUARDO LAS VARIABLES DE LA BD PARA SER USADAS EN PANEL-CONTROL.PHP
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 800000);

    echo "Bienvenido! ".$_SESSION['usuario'];
    echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>PANEL DE CONTROL</a>";

    }   
        else
        { 
        echo "Usuario o contraseña estan incorrectos.";
        echo "<br><a href='logearse.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";

        }
 mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Luego de que se loguea la persona puede ver el siguiente panel-de-control.php el cual tiene un bloque en php donde se inicia la sesión y una parte HTML en el cual hay dos cajas de texto

```
<?php
session_start();
$now = time();

if($now > $_SESSION['expire'])
{
    session_destroy();
    echo "Su sesion a terminado,
    <a href='index.html'>Necesita Hacer Login</a>";
    exit;
}
?>
<HTML>
  <body>
    <input id=input1>
    <input id=input2>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Cómo podría no mostrar las dos cajas para el usuario llamemoslo X, es decir, que solo se muestre una caja en este caso el input1 ya que el no tiene permiso para eso, y para el usuario Z que tiene privilegios elevados si pueda ver las dos cajas, me imagino eso se hace con codigo PHP dentro del HTML en el cual se valida el usuario y la caja 1 debe ir dentro de ese codigo ¿estoy en lo cierto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir a la base de datos el campo "privilegios", ahora, supongamos que el usuario "x" tiene rango 0, y el "z" tiene rango 1 (rangos o privilegios, como lo veas), entonces en el panel de control al mostrar los INPUT sería de este modo:

```
<HTML>
  <body>
<?php
echo '<input id=input1>'; /*Esto lo mostramos siempre, ya que eso lo puede 
ver el rango 0 y el 1*/
if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 0){
    echo '<input id=input2>';
}
php>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

El código está basado en que sólo usaras 2 inputs, ya si quieres usar más sería mejor meter un SWITCH, te añado el código debajo:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"> <!--Abrimos un form para usar 
la accion "PHP_SELF" -->
<input type ="text" name = "rango"> <!--He añadido esta opción para añadir el rango 
mediante un textbox, ya que no cuento con la base de datos, pero en tu caso 
no es necesario -->
<input type="submit" name="verrango" value="Escuchar"> <!--Usaré el botón 
"verrango" para ejecutar el "submit" y que se pueda realizar el "PHP_SELF"-->
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["verrango"])) /*Al realizarse el "PHP_SELF se vuelven a 
realizar los codigos PHP, entonces se vuelve a ejecutar este IF*/
{
switch ($_POST["rango"]) {
    case '0':
?>  <input id=input1> <?php /*Este input siempre se va a mostrar, ya que lo 
mira el rango 0*/
    break;
    case '1':
?>  <input id=input1>
    <input id=input2> <?php /*En este caso ya se muestran 2 inputs*/
    break;
    case '2':
?>  <input id=input1>  
    <input id=input2>
    <input id=input3> <?php /*En este caso ya se muestran 3 inputs*/
    break;
    default:
    echo 'No tienes permisos para ver los inputs'; /*Mandamos un error en 
caso de que el rango no se encuentre en los disponibles*/
    break;
}}?>
```

He usado el metodo que sugirió @Juanjoo Tocino. Sobre la repetición del código, sí, hay una forma de evitar poner todos los inputs nuevamente dependiendo del rango, y hacer ese código más pequeño. Pero me gustaría que primero intentaras tú encontrar la lógica a ese problema, y si realmente no puedes, me pides ayuda.

Comment: Una tontería pero el IF tiene un solo =

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya está arreglado, igual pudiste editarlo tú...

Comment: Otra cosa que me gustaría añadir (no puedo comentar tu respuesta por mi baja reputación); en tu código sólo muestras el INPUT de rango 0 si el rango es = 0, más también se debería mostrar si es rango = 1

Comment: Hola, sí omití la lógica del problema quería mostrar el hecho de no mezclar código HTML dentro de un echo de PHP.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertodeTriana en caso de que fueran muchos como seria el Switch, podrias darme un ejemplo?

Comment: @GabrielUribeGomez disculpa, apenas vi tu comentario, ahora te paso el código editando mi respuesta, si te sirve como solución, ¿podrías marcarla como valida?

Answer (score 0):

Para no "embeber" código HTML dentro de un echo de PHP hay una solución mas apropiada y es realizar lo siguiente:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 0):?>
<input id=input1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 1):?>
<input id=input2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Tomando el extracto del ejemplo anterior.